# User shiny doesn't seem to "see" .bashrc file

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I'm running Ubuntu 20 on a Digital Ocean droplet.
I use R and [RStudio's Shiny-Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/).

When I use a Terminal logged in as user:me the prompt is customized and the cursor up error brings up the previous command. This is handy.

However, when I login as user:shiny the prompt is "$".

/home/shiny/.bashrc has code that looks like it would customize the prompt.

Why is the prompt not customized and how do I get it to be customized?

An excerpt from /home/shiny/.bashrc:

```
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Comment: when you login to `shiny` what's the output of `echo $SHELL`?  It probably is using `/bin/sh` which is the default that user adding sets the shell to if you don't tell it to use Bash; we can find out with the simple `echo` once you are logged in to that user.

Comment: The output is: /bin/sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bashrc` is only read by the **Bash shell**.  If you didn't specify the shell on user creation, it's using `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.  Hence why shell customization doesn't run.

Start by running `chsh` when in the `shiny` user.  Enter `/bin/bash` when it asks for a path.  It will ask for the user password, enter it.  This should then change the default shell for the user.  Log out of the user and log in again and it should default to using Bash.

Comment: Very clear instructions. Thanks!